# Timestamp to string with custom format

Tags: google-bigquery

I am to move data from BigQuery to an Oracle database and am trying to find the best way to deal with timestamps. The Oracle DB can only import csv files with dates in little endian format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss) but by default BigQuery only supports big endian (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss).

```sql
SELECT
  t,
  STRING(t) s
FROM
  (SELECT TIMESTAMP(132456789101112) t)
```

```
Row   t                         s
1     1974-03-14 01:33:09 UTC   1974-03-14 01:33:09.101112
```

I could of course extract the different components of the timestamp and paste them together manually (see below) or write some clever UDF, but I'd be surprised if there isn't any way to do this with BigQuery's standard functionality. It seems like such a common thing to do that I've in fact hesitated to ask for some time.

```sql
SELECT
  t,
  CONCAT(
    RIGHT(CONCAT("0", STRING(DAY(t))), 2), "/",
    RIGHT(CONCAT("0", STRING(MONTH(t))), 2), "/",
    RIGHT(CONCAT("000", STRING(YEAR(t))), 4), " ",
    TIME(t)
  ) s
FROM
  (SELECT TIMESTAMP(132456789101112) t)
```

```
Row   t                         s    
1     1974-03-14 01:33:09 UTC   14/03/1974 01:33:09
```

Is there anything like `FORMAT(t, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss")` or a way to do it with regexps? (Without having to concat several `REGEXP_EXTRACT`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check [STRFTIME_UTC_USEC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#strftime_utc_usec)

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

or with your example

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP(132456789101112), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 10):

For those of you using Bigquery's standard SQL, the right way to do this is with

`FORMAT_TIMESTAMP` or `FORMAT_DATE` depending on your input.

ex:

`SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y/%m/%d', TIMESTAMP('2017-11-01'))`
will return 
`2017/11/01`

Answer (score 1):

Its not a straightforward function, but it does the job...

```
SELECT
  t,
  CONCAT( LPAD(STRING(DAY(t)),2,"0"),"/",LPAD(STRING(MONTH(t)),2,"0"),"/",STRING(YEAR(t))," ",TIME(t)) s
FROM (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP(132456789101112) t)
```